# log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender

Tags: log4j

I put Inside the file - log4j.properties -

```
# Change the line below to adjust ZK client logging

log4j.logger.org.apache.zookeeper=INFO, ROLLINGFILE
log4j.logger.org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient=INFO, ROLLINGFILE
log4j.appender.ROLLINGFILE.File=${zookeeper.log.dir}/zookeeper.log
log4j.appender.ROLLINGFILE.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.ROLLINGFILE.MaxBackupIndex=10
```

log4j reports an error:

```
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.ROLLINGFILE
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "ROLLINGFILE".
log4j:ERROR Could not find value for key log4j.appender.ROLLINGFILE
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "ROLLINGFILE".
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include new errors, not post as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Error is self descriptive

> Could not find value for key `log4j.appender.ROLLINGFILE`

You're missing this line to initialize the class

```
log4j.appender.ROLLINGFILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
```

Unclear why you didn't copy the existing ones that Kafka uses to use it for Zookeeper

https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/config/log4j.properties#L24

Comment: i didn't see on the config file any "file size" limit, that is my problem - the file gets to big 3.3gb

Comment: You can always add that, but doesn't change that you still need to define the appender class

Comment: the file is rotating, i added limit 30KB and it reached 37KB now, any advice?

Comment: It'll never be exact unless you expect truncated log lines. Although, 7+ kb in the buffer does seem like a lot